# Laravel Dropbox File Upload: InvalidArgumentException in Client.php line 1473:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload file with dropbox Api, for that I have used [flysystem-dropbox](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-dropbox) package.

My route:

```
Route::get('/dropbox-upload-file',[
    'uses'=>'FileController@dropboxFileUpload',
    'as'=> 'dropbox-upload-file'
    ]);
```

Controller Code:

```
  public function dropboxFileUpload()
    {
        $Client = new Client(config('filesystems.dropbox.key'), config('filesystems.dropbox.secret'));
        $file = fopen(public_path('images/angular_crud.png'), 'rb');
        $size = filesize(public_path('images/angular_crud.png'));
        $dropboxFileName = '/dropboxfile-name.png';
        $Client->uploadFile($dropboxFileName,WriteMode::add(),$file, $size);
    }
```

So while I tried to access the Route I got the following Error:

> ```
> InvalidArgumentException in Client.php line 1473:
> 'accessToken' invalid: can't be null
> ```

I have followed the following Tutorial:

[Laravel file upload with dropbox](http://www.expertphp.in/article/working-with-dropbox-api-to-upload-file-using-league-flysystem-dropbox-package-with-example-in-laravel-52)

If anyone face the problem before or got the solution, please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the dropbox key and secret array within the disks array, in *config/filesystems.php*, you'll have to change the first line in dropboxFileUpload().

to:

```
$Client = new Client(config('filesystems.disks.dropbox.key'), config('filesystems.disks.dropbox.secret'));
```